# align text outside table with column in table in CSS

Tags: css

I have a table with 9 columns, and under column 8, I want to print that column's total (which I have stored in a variable).  How do I align the text so that it appears under column 8?

I currently have the total in a h5 tag, but if that prevents the alignment, I'm willing to change it.

```
<table> ...stuff
</table>
<h5>TOTAL!</h5>    <---- this should appear under column 8 of the table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all columns are of equal width:

```
.p9 { /* p9 for 9 column table of equal width */
  width: 11%;
}
h5 {
  margin-left: 88%; /* 11 x 8 */
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="p9">
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h5>TOTAL!</h5>
```

Comment: the columns are not currently of equal width, but i may resort to setting the width in order to get the correct positioning.

Answer (score 1):

The best route would be to have it in the table itself however if that isn't an option, align your h5 by using javascript. Get the x offset of column 8 and apply that value to your h5. If you can provide a more full example of your markup I can provide an example.

Edit:

Since you didn't provide markup I created an example. You should be able to apply the gist of it to your code.

**html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>head 1</td>
            <td>head 2</td>
            <td id="totalcol">head 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>body 1</td>
            <td>body 2</td>
            <td>body 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p id="total">Some total</p>
```

**js**

```
var left = $('#totalcol').offset().left;
$("#total").css("margin-left",left);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H62wV/

Comment: I'd prefer to have the total outside of the table.  I've posted the code for the table here: [link] (http://pastebin.com/3qyhzb1G)

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post the HTML output of the PHP with dummy data.

Comment: I want the subtotal and total to line up with the Invoice Total column, but outside the table.  [link] http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/1369/xbo1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Is your table an actual HTML table or CSS divs behaving like a table?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you are going the table way, you should take it till the end.

To show  a third column total, I would do:

```
<TABLE>
<THEAD>
     <TR>
     <td>head 1</td>
     <td>head 2</td>
     <td>head 3</td>
    </tr>
</THEAD>
<TFOOT>
     <TR>
     <td></td>              <<-- notice the empty cells
     <td></td>
     <td>TOTAL</td>   
    </tr>
</TFOOT>
<TBODY>
     <TR>
     <td>body 1</td>
     <td>body 2</td>
     <td>body 3</td>
    </tr>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

This way the alignment is automatic.
(Notice that the footer recomended position is before the body)

Comment: the table is paginated, and with this method, it makes it look like the total should only be for the records on the page.  i need the total to be outside of the table (for other reasons as well).

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! Bad luck that it didn't help you, but I like to have a feedback, even negative.